# Run postinstall hook for any local dependency

Tags: node.js, npm

If we have this:

```
{
  "scripts":{
    "postinstall":"./scripts/postinstall.sh"
  }
}
```

Then this postinstall hook will run whenever we do an

`$ npm install`

At the command line

What I am wondering however, is if there is a way to run a postinstall hook when we install a dependency like this

`$ npm install x`

Is there some NPM hook that we can use for that?

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer** There's no functionality built-in to npm which provides this kind of hook that I'm aware of.

---

**Possible solution**, albeit a bash one, would be to completely override the `npm install x` command with your own custom logic. For example:

1. Create a `.sh` script as follows. Lets name the file `custom-npm-install.sh`:

   ```sh
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   npm() {
     if [[ $* == "install "* || $* == "i "* ]]; then

       # When running `$ npm install <name>` (i.e. `$ npm install ...` followed
       # by a space char and some other chars such as a package name - run
       # the command provided.
       command npm "$@"

       # Then run a pseudo `postinstall` command, such as another shell script.
       command path/to/postinstall.sh
     else
       # Run the `$ npm install` command and all others as per normal.
       command npm "$@"
     fi
   }
   ```
2. Add the following snippet to your `.bash_profile` file *( Note: you'll need to define the actual path to `custom-npm-install.sh`)*:

   ```sh
   # Custom logic applied when the `npm install <name>` or the
   # shorthand equivalent `npm i <name>` command is run.
   . path/to/custom-npm-install.sh
   ```

---

**Notes**

1. After configuring your `.bash_proile` as per point two above, you'll need to create a new terminal session/window for it to be effective. The logic will be effective in all terminal sessions thereafter.
2. Now, whenever you run `npm install <name>` or the many other variations such as:

   - `npm install <name>@<version>`
   - `npm install <name> <name> --save-dev`
   - `npm i -D <name>`
   - *etc, etc...*

   `custom-npm-install.sh` will run the command as per normal and then run the command `./scripts/postinstall.sh` (i.e. whatever the subsequently given command is set to).
3. All other npm commands will be run as normal, e.g. `npm install`
4. Given `custom-npm-install.sh` current logic the `./scripts/postinstall.sh` will be run whenever `npm install <name> ...` is entered via the CLI. However, if you wanted it to run *ONLY* when a specific package is installed then you'll need to change the conditional logic in the `if` statement. For example if you want `./scripts/postinstall.sh` to run *ONLY* when installing [`shelljs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs) then change the `if` statement to:

   ```sh
   if [[ $* == "install "*" shelljs"* || $* == "i "*" shelljs"* ]];
   ```

Comment: thanks, yeah, this isn't just for my own use, it's for a library..so I was hoping I could give users a plug-n-play solution where they just add a hook to the package.json scripts...hmmm

Comment: There's definitely no plug-n-play solution. What 's the use case is for such a feature tho? _(My curiosity is killing me !)_

Comment: I have this project which is actually very awesome: https://github.com/ORESoftware/npm-link-up

Comment: Typically, it runs `npm link` for all projects. But after doing that, if you run `npm install x` in a project, it will often break symlinks. So I need a way to re-symlink projects after an install. So re-symlinking would happen in a postinstall script for `npm install x`.

Comment: I lot of people use Lerna instead of `npm-link-up`, but I actually think that `nlu` is far superior - Lerna was created by the Babel team, so got more exposure.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Alexander. Yeah, it's certainly a requirement that's difficult to fulfil.