# Hook (specifically postinstall) after any npm install command

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Using NPM at the command line, is there some official hook that I can configure, which means that for any `npm install` command (including `npm install x`), a certain hook is run?

Right now, I see certain limitations -

if I run `npm install x` it will not run hooks for another dependency (obviously) but it also doesn't seem to run hooks for the main/parent package.

Plain old `npm install` will run preinstall / postintall hooks for the main/parent package.

Comment: There's no functionality built-in to npm to provide the kind of hook you're wanting that I'm aware of. I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48983841/run-postinstall-hook-for-any-local-dependency/48987576#48987576) regarding the `postinstall` hook. The solution entailed overriding the `npm install x` command with your own custom logic via a shell script.

Comment: So you want that when someone adds your package to their repo your postinstall should be called? Or you want that after installing your package, any npm install will call your hook?

Comment: @TarunLalwani, once the user installs my package, any subsequent `npm install` command, would run a hook...the hook would be run for any other package that gets installed. probably not possible, but just wondering.

Comment: If you want to share what your package's intentions are (the final task you want it to do, hence the need for the 'hook'), maybe I or someone else can help you out with another solution, since depending on altering the original behaviour of `npm install` does not seem as something practical

Comment: @Olegzandr, this is as good as a unintentional/intentional virus, Imagine I install your package and every time I install a package, you want to run something of your own. This could do anything, report the packages i install or something else

Answer (score 0):

If you are on **npm v6.X** it's possible to run scripts on `npm install <package>` by using [Hook Scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts#hook-scripts).
Unfortunately it seems the functionality has been [removed in newer versions](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2692).

In order to do so you need to create a script inside `node_modules/.hooks/{eventname}` where `{eventname}` is the event you want to hook on.
For example to hook on `postinstall` you'll need `node_modules/.hooks/postinstall`

There's a catch though: it won't run on Windows, because it won't be able to recognize the file as an executable since it's lacking a file extension.

A *not so pretty* workaround is to create, for instance, a `postinstall.cmd` and soft (or hard `/H`) linking it with `mklink postinstall postinstall.cmd`

This will ensure that Windows recognizes the file as a `.cmd` executable to correctly run it.